# How to configure security group on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

Ok, I have an application on ElasticBeanstalk and have setup an EC2 server for my database.

I've been trying to limit the connections to the database to my IP and that of the applications (EB), however all configurations I have tried have not worked.

I have tried using the security group ID - where on the security group ID used by the App had a outgoing connection to the DB and the DB security group had an incoming connection from the security group ID from the App.

Unfortunately that didn't work. And I don't know how to find the CIDR for the EB environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: For development and troubleshooting purposes, I usually find it easier to have more open access in my security groups, and once a connection is verified it's easier to incrementally tighten things up to where you feel comfortable.

Comment: Security group ID is the way to go. I would leave the outgoing security group rules wide open though, and just restrict the inbound access in the security group assigned to the DB.

Comment: @MrDukI have done that. I'm at point where I've removed all apart from one which is open to every IP and I'd like to restrict it.

Comment: Add security group rules that allows only connections from your home IP and application static IP (private IP) on ec2 serve that's running your db.

Comment: @naveenkerati how do I find the private IP?

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK as launching environment in elasticbeanstalk creates an Ec2 instance you can check it from ec2 console .

Answer (score 0):

Add the security group on ec2 server to allow the traffic from your home IP and elasticbeanstalk appliaction static IP.
you can find the Elasticbeanstalk application static IP from Ec2 console Or you can use the following command using amazon cli.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids <instance-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a windows machine on AWS EC2, and I wanted that only I should be able to connect from my MAC to it, using remote desktop client.

Inbound Rule is used for incoming traffic and outbound rule is used for outgoing traffic.

Since I wanted to connect using Remote Desktop, in the inbound rule of security group I selected "RDP" and then in the source I selected 'My Ip' and thus I secured my ec2 instance such that only I can access it
[image]